# How to print selected web pages in Landscape or portrait

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement, need to prepare a report with 100s of pages which contains Charts or Images. I am using ASP.NET, High charts, HTML, jQuery, CSS/Bootstrap to achieve the same.

Requirement is to print Charts in landscape mode and Images in portrait mode. I know which page will contain chart/Image. Can we achieve this behavior with CSS or any other alternatives? Need to print whole content as a single pdf.

Please suggest...

Comment: I think you can only set print orientation at HTML page level. You can't specify the orientation of printed pages individually.

Comment: My assumption was same. But am trying to learn expert's ideas or advice before I talk and convince client manager.

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet, you could transform the images you want to print landscape.

```
@media print {
    .chart {
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}
```

More or less. There would be more to it, but something like that might get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.. will try to use transform

Comment: Transform rotated as expected. See issues now with height and width.  before transformation height:650px; width:930px worked well in landscape mode. Now I am trying to rotate charts in portrait mode..Charts are overlapping instead of displaying one chart per page though I use footer class after every chart footer {
        page-break-after: always;
    }.. am I missing something?